# Seleccionar solo números en el query de mysql

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

tengo un query de sql server y funciona perfecto, el problema es que el output arroja:**[(Decimal('0.000'),**
cómo hago para que solo me arroje los números. Aquí les dejo el comando, estoy haciendo la consulta desde python.

```
cursor1.execute("SELECT sum(Peso_neto) from Ticket WHERE Fecha between '"+str('2022-01-22')+"' and '"+str('2023-02-23')+"' AND cast(Producto as nvarchar(max))= '"+str(producto)+"' AND cast(Proveedor as nvarchar(max))='' ")
```

Intenté usar **isnumeric()** pero lo que hace es sumar el número de pesos y no los pesos en si. Si alguien puede ayudarme, muchar gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando instrucciones de SQL Server. Guiándome del título que dice **query de mysql**, con el módulo [mysql.connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/):

```py
cursor1.execute("""SELECT sum(Peso_neto) 
    FROM Ticket 
    WHERE Fecha between %s and %s 
    AND Producto = %s
    AND Proveedor = %s
    """, 
    ['2022-01-22', '2022-02-23', producto, proveedor]
)
```

Si estás usando el módulo [mariadb](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/), reemplaza los `%s` por `?`